# What's the differences between Object Storage and Key-Value Database?

Tags: database, key-value-store, object-storage

It seems a same thing from users aspect.

Answer (score 5):

A key-value database does not care about the contents or format of the value. It just allows you to store stuff under keys, and get it back again, and iterate keys.

Object Storage or Document Databases can look at the contents of the data you store in them, and allow you to query or index on something other than the key.

The would be one distinction to draw. But googling around for Object Storage, it seems that this is a rather ill-defined buzzword.

Comment: Can apparently mean integrating into a programming language to persist "live" objects (so that would be something very much different): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881088/what-is-object-storage-wrt-cloud-computing

Answer (score 0):

First of all, storage backend and database are two product forms. Storage backend can be different storage models such as kv / block / device, and database has more data models. So both just follow the same data model.